# Sass Mixin Parameter - Stop Sass from converting Fraction (e.g. 1/3 converts to 0.33333)?

Tags: css, variables, sass, include, mixins

## Situation

I have a Mixin like this:

```
@mixin column($fraction: null) {
    // ...do stuff with $fraction
}
```

It can be used like so:

```
@include column('1/3');
```

Please note:

1. A String is passed
2. I need the denominator (3) to do some nth-child magic.

This works (used str-index + str-slice).

## Problem

Now I'd like to make the quotes optional.
Meaning, this also needs to work:

```
@include column(1/3); // no quotes
```

Sass treats this as a number. Thats fine. 
But it always does **a division before I can do anything with the variable**.

## Example

Include:

```
@include column(1/3);
```

Mixin:

```
@mixin column($fraction: null) {
    $myVar: $fraction // $fraction equals '0.3333333' at this point already
}
```

Is there a way to prevent Sass from doing that?
Or another way to get the denominator?

Thanks!

---

## Additional Notes

**About using a Comma instead of Slash**

As proposed by @Johannes Reuter I could just use a comma instead of a slash:

`@include column(1,3);`

Unfortunately means that the include looses a bit of meaning.
With a "1/3" it's clear that the column will be one third in width. I'd like to keep that.

It especially gets confusing with more parameters:

```
@include column(1, 3, 3, stacking);
```

vs

```
@include column(1/3, 3, stacking);
```

But thanks a lot for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is a dirty trick but if you use argument list you get the value without division, then you have to convert in to string for extract the second value with `str-slice`:

**SASS**

```
@mixin column($fraction...) {
  $fraction: $fraction + "";
  $n:str-slice($fraction, 3);
  &:nth-child(#{$n}){
    display:block;
  }
}

.class{
  @include column(1/3);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
.class:nth-child(3) {
  display: block;
}
```

**PS:** The problem is if you want to use more parameters. I don't know how to solve it.

---

**UPDATE 28/09/2016**

I found a way to do with two mixins, one with a list of parameters and the css properties and another one with **variable arguments** where I extract the number after division operator.

Variable arguments prevents doing the division but all the parameter go together and if I extract the 1st parameter the division doing again. Using two diferent mixins I can use the variable arguments and at the same time maintain separate parameters:

**SASS**

```
@mixin column2($col, $gutter) { 
  width: $col * 100%;
  padding: $gutter;
}

@mixin column($args...) { 
  $args-str: inspect($args);
  $separator: str-index($args-str, ",");
  $separator2: str-index($args-str, "/");
  $fraction: str-slice($args-str, 1, $separator - 1);
  $cols: unquote(str-slice($fraction, $separator2 + 1));
  &:nth-child(#{$cols}){
    @include column2($args...);
  }
}

.class {
  @include column(1/3, 3px);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
.class:nth-child(3) {
  width: 33.33333%;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

Comment: Oh, that's interesting. I'll play around with this. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure, but this could work with an arglist: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21418566/pass-sass-list-to-mixin-with-multiple-arguments

I'll try tonight. Thanks for bringing that to my attention!

Comment: Hmm... strange. Even with the arglist I get a "0.33333" sting instead of an "1/3" string. Very strange.

Comment: Yes, so I say dirty trick, is a weird behaviord. I found another way to convert in to string with `inspect()` but I'm not able to integrate into the mixin:   `@include column(inspect(1/3))`

Comment: @Arrowcatch I edit the answer, I think I have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the numerator and the denominator as two separate parameters:

Include:

```
@include column(1,3);
```

Mixin:

```
@mixin column($numerator: null, $denominator: null) {
 //...
}
```

This would be much cleaner than string-operations.

Comment: Hey Johannes, 
thanks for the reply. I've thought about this. What I don't like about it is, that the include looses a bit of meaning. With @include column(1/3); it's just clear, that the column will be 1/3 in width. I'd like to keep that intact.

Comment: Also: I will add this to the original question.