# How to inject literal string into scss @mixin

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

Considering this following scss code:

```
@mixin homeSlider(
    $dim: 150px,
    $h1: "h1 { font-size: 4em; margin-top: 0; }"
){
    section {
        margin-top: -$dim;
    }
    $h1;
 }

 @include homeSlider( $dim: 50px, $h1: "h1 { font-size: 3em; margin-top: 0; }" )
```

I need to know how is it possible to achieve my goal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
@mixin homeSlider($dim, $h1-font-size){
    section {
        margin-top: -$dim;

        h1 {
           font-size: $h1-font-size;
           margin-top: 0;
        }
    }
}


@include homeSlider(50px, 3em;)  /* $dim = 50px - $h1-font-size = 3em; */
```

Comment: A quite good but this could be quickly verbose if we have several params. I was thinking of a kind of shortcut.

Comment: Not sure I understand, but if you want more parameters/arguments, I suggest you look into [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21418566/pass-sass-list-to-mixin-with-multiple-arguments)